# Image background transparent GIMP

Tags: image, transparency, gimp

I have a few jpg images and I need to have a transparent background. I will add these images in a web page and I need to see just the main element of the image and the web page beneath.
Does anyone know how to transform an image in one with a transparent background?
I have GIMP.
Thanks

Comment: Using image-editing tools like GIMP is off-topic here. You might try http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use a PNG as your output, JPEG images can't contain transparency, and GIF's only have binary transparency, ie full on or full off.  Haven't used GIMP in a (long) while, but you can try the tutorial here: [Transparent PNG](http://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-using-web-transparency.html)

Comment: Indeed - open the layers dialog (ctrl + L), reight click on the thumbnail, and select "add alpha channel". Select your background and edit->cut - this renders it transparent, and save as .PNG