# how to make a jpeg image semi transparent using gimp?

Tags: jpeg, gimp, alpha-transparency

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Image background transparent GIMP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8835629/image-background-transparent-gimp)

I've a jpeg image. i'd like to make it more transparent as i'm using it in my android app as a background. It will have textview in front of it and the image's colours can clash with text in the views.

How can i increase transparency using GIMP?

Comment: `jpeg` doesn't store alpha information. You might want to change its type.

Comment: @PulkitGoyal Hi i've exported it as a png, how would i change the alpha channel. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A JPEG image can not support an alpha channel (transparency) and so you would need to use a file format that can. My recommendation would be .PNG

Comment: Hi, i've now exported it as a png. How would i change the alpha value. In my android app i have this as a jpeg and the listview that is in front of this image, i have set the listview's background to #ccffffff. This works well. i just need to set the background of other activities that dont have listviews. This means there will be consistency in app. thanks